# Add Groovy to IntelliJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy

I am working on a project where unit tests are written in Groovy, when I am trying to launch the tests I am getting "**Groovyc: parsing failed**" error. I tried to do some few changes randomly, when I added groovy jar file in global libraries, the error disappeared but then I got another error.
It seems I should implement groovy into intellij but I'm not a groovy expert, any idea what is causing these groovy errors and how to fix them?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206224119-How-to-configure-new-Groovy-SDK?page=1#community_comment_360000152759) help?

Comment: I am checking but the weired thing is when I go to add framework support and I tick the groovy box, then when I click ok and try to open again the add framework support I find groovy unticked, is that normal>?

Comment: If your project is Maven or Gradle based, the dependency should be added via pom.xml/build.gradle file instead.

Comment: yes it is maven based , but is there other way?other than adding it in pom?

Comment: No, if your project uses Groovy, it must be added in pom.xml.

Comment: note that when I run mvn test the test runs normally, however when I right click on the unit test of the class and try to run the test it fails now with another error (groovyc internal error) , any clue?

Comment: Hard to say, if possible, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the steps to reproduce this issue.